# Oracle ORA-00911, query with several coalesce

Tags: php, oracle

I have this query

```
Select * from mytable WHERE  coalesce(f1,n' ') = ? and  coalesce(f2,n' ') = ? and  coalesce(f3,n' ') = ? and  coalesce(f4,n' ') = ?
```

f1, f2, f3 and f4 are nvarchar2 fields

I call the query from php with the value `array(0,0,0,0)`

I get:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

When I reduce the query to one coalesce statement, like

```
Select * from mytable WHERE  coalesce(f1,n' ') = ?
```

called with array(0),

it works.

When I change the values in the array from 0 to whatever, it does not change anything. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: You haven't shown it above, but does your statement end with a semicolon (`;`)? If it does, [remove it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987882/how-can-i-solve-ora-00911-invalid-character).

Comment: no,  it doesn't, must be something else

Comment: Can you show the php code?

Comment: i use adodb as a a database abstraction, so the real query must be hidden in the library

Answer (score 0):

Without your php code, I can only guess that you're calling the select statement by sending the array, instead of listing each value in the array separately.