# How to know the if remainder of a division is 0 in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello I am trying to know iF a year iS a leap-year, because i only want leap years to be inserted on the table olympics, but an error keeps coming up.

This is my attempt in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE OLYMPICS
ADD CONSTRAINT LEAP_YEAR
CHECK((YEAR%4)=0);
```

And this is the error:

911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
     *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
            letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
            character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
            any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
            (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
            delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
            Reference Manual.

Comment: MySQL does not implement check constraints, so this will have no effect.  Either use a trigger or don't bother.  BTW, the winder olympics are in the alternative even years.

Comment: The actual formula is `year%4=0 AND (year%100!=0 OR year%400=0)` but hey, [close enough is probably fine](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/blog/2009/jan/01/zune-firmware-mistake).

Comment: @tadman based on the table name they don’t need actual leap years anyway. There was a Summer Olympics in 1900.

Comment: @MartinSmith Then this code is more for "every four years" than "every leap year". Good point.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql] when error message is clearly from [tag:oracle]?  cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27987882/1695906

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you could do something like this

```
  DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(YEARVARIABLE,'-12-31'))
```

And then determine if it is 366 or 365 days

```
  Select DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(2016,'-12-31')) 
  Result = 366  (yes leap year)

  Select DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(2015,'-12-31')) 
  Result = 365 (no leap year)
```

The devided by 4 does not work, because not every year devided by 4 is a leap year

Comment: This is a MySQL question, so be careful when giving advice for unrelated platforms.

Comment: mhh ok, in my head sql tag is always SQL server unless explicitly specified otherwise. In the Question that is not the case. The only indicator is the mysql tag. So to be sure I posted the SQL server answer as well, but ok. I have deleted it.

Comment: There is `[mysql]` in the tags list. SQL is a general thing, SQL server questions are probably 20% of all SQL questions based on what I've seen. It's a fairly rare platform with Postgres and MySQL being far more popular.

Comment: @tadman MySQL yes, Postgres no. There are 76,976 questions with that tag, compared with 217,648 for SQL Server and 495,879 MySQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith That is based on all-time. I bet the last year skews differently, but your point is valid. One problem is that MySQL questions do get auto-tagged as SQL Server with annoying frequency.

Comment: Not seeing a massively different skew. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+created%3A2017  And https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+created%3A2017 so a ratio of 2.5 to 1 which is a bit lower than the all time ratio.