# 'invalid character' error in Oracle Express Database

Tags: sql, oracle-xe

SO I have a project I'm working on where I'm porting code originally written for MySQL over to Oracle Express(10g). I've got most of the code working, however, I have one error that seems to persist despite my debugging attempts. the error's `ORA-00911: invalid character` from this real small bit of code:

```
INSERT INTO driver VALUES (3,'Cal','9024919999');
INSERT INTO driver VALUES (4,'Dan','9024914545');
COMMIT;
```

also here is the definition of the table that I'm inserting into:

```
CREATE TABLE Driver(
    d_id integer,
    d_name varchar2(50),
    d_contact varchar2(30),
     CONSTRAINT Driver_d_id PRIMARY KEY(d_id)
);
```

Any suggestions y'all have would be  super appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve ORA-00911: invalid character error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987882/how-can-i-solve-ora-00911-invalid-character-error)

Comment: Run it as single commands: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00015c8d338c97282d15e309f2cbb9fd