# Oracle basic multi-statement block

Tags: oracle

In SQL Server, multiple statements in SSMS can be performed.  In Oracle (using toad), I don't know why I receive certain errors doing the same thing.  For example, I assume an Oracle requirement is to place them in a block, but I still get the following:

```
DECLARE
  v_datetime TIMESTAMP := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  insert into sometable_log values (v_datetime, 'this is a test ',1);
  select * from sometable_log where event_dt = v_datetime;
END;
```

produces:

> [Error] Execution (5: 1): ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PLS-00428: an
>   INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Why would I need to use an into clause?  Can someone please help me understand what this is?

Thank you!

Comment: In PL/SQL, you need an `into` clause so you can capture the value for further processing. If you want to return a ref cursor implicitly to the caller from a PL/SQL block, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/230471

Comment: If you just want to run two commands one after another in Toad rather than coding anything in PL/SQL, then consult the Toad documentation (I don't use it).

Comment: It doesn't seem like you really do want a PL/SQL block. It would probably be more useful to say what errors you get running the plain SQL statements  [Maybe this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23029246/266304)

Answer (score 0):

When executing the block of code, Oracle expects that the select command should have some code-like effect.  That's why it wants you to add the into clause.

To do what you need, just move the select statement outside of the PL/SQL begin/end block.

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  If I do that, then it will not recognize v_datetime variable.  So, is the difference that Oracle doesn't work in batch , as does Sql Server?  It seems that there is a fundamental difference between the way PL/SQL and Sql Server works, and that looks to me that PLSQL handles only one statement at a time in batch fashion.  Am I correct?